# Python/Django mirror or proxy app

Tags: python, django, proxy, mirror

I need to setup a mirror/proxy site using Django/Python. What I need to do

I have a site say abc.com.

If I go to abc.com/stackoverflow.com, I want all content to be served from my server at abc.com. This includes all JS, CSS and images.

So I want a django mirror/proxy app, which takes a url, rewrites the html, pulls the htmls and content and servers it from a local mirror.

[Edit]
I prefer a Django app, but a non-Django python app would be good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a [vhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) setup. You have to connect multiple domain names so that they are served by the same web server. That is accomplished by pointing the domains to the same server and setting up vhosting there. Django, or other software that serves the pages aren't directly involved in it.

Comment: If I want abc.com/google.com to mirror google.com, how does vhosts come in play.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to copy the content of a whole site you do not own and serve it from your own domain? Then use wget to scrape the files and host them using a web server. Remember to rewrite all urls so that they point to your servers domain. Do you want to make it seem like you are hosting the material while it actually exists on a remote site? Then use a simple iframe.